# How do I navigate to a previous page within a site opened using WebView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have an app that was created using React Native. In this app I have 2 screens (Home and View Web). In the View Web screen I am opening a webpage inside of a WebView. As an example, let's say the webpage being opened is Stack Overflow (Page A). My problem arises when the user clicks on a link within the Stack Overflow page (Page A), and then navigates to a different page on the site (Page B). When the user wants to go back to the original Stack Overflow page opened within the WebView (Page A), it won't let them, and instead navigates them back to the Home Screen.

Here is what I want to occur:

- If the user is on Page B and they hit a back button, I want them to go back to Page A.
- If the user is already on Page A and they hit the back button, I want them to go back to the Home Screen.

My question basically boils down to this: Is there a way for a single button to not only allow the user to navigate between pages inside of a WebView, but also allow for navigation between screens in the app itself? If so, please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview, you can check the functions `goBack();`

Comment: Right. That function allowed to maneuver from Page B back to Page A, but it doesn't work when trying to go from Page A to the Home Screen. Is there a way that a single button could work to accomplish both?